# Is there a way to enforce tls encryption for particular recipients

Tags: sendgrid

According to the documentation you can [enforce TLS encryption at the user level](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/settings-enforced-tls/retrieve-current-enforced-tls-settings), however, we need to enforce TLS encryption for only for specific emails.

It seems there is not, and if this is the case, is there any workaround to achieve this?

Is it possible to do this at the "sub user" level? Would we have to have two separate sendgrid accounts?

I looked through the documentation but could not find any more flexible ways of enforcing TLS encryption.